# 日本語に違和感: 「編集済みのタグ」？

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

時々見かけて微妙な違和感を感じ，しかしそのまま気にせずいたのですが，編集内容の要約で時々見かける

> 編集済みのタグ

（例えば [この編集](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/95/3), また「編集済みのタイトル」も[例があります](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6142/4)．いずれも無作為に選んだものです．）

これ，もしかしてデフォルトで挿入される文言であって，

> Edited tag

ということでしょうか．であれば，この `Edited` は名詞にかかる形(tag which is edited)ではない用法であって，この日本語では意図された内容を伝えていないと思います．

Comment: [Transifex上](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289308?q=edited%20tags)に適用しました。

Comment: @jmac meta 上での役割は終わったとみなして accept しました．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

変更案：

> タグを編集

,

> タイトルを編集

完全な文章にして

> タグを編集しました

でもいいと思いますが，必要ないと思います．